# Ajax and store session in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I Like to store a id in session using AJAX in laravel,In normal php and jQuery i am using the following method ,& how to attain the same in laravel

**Normal Method:**

```
$('.action').click(function(){
    var editaction=($(this).attr("id"));
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
      url:"test_session.php",
      data:"test_id="+editaction,
      success:function(results){
        window.location.href="newredirect.php"
      }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You can copy paste that code and put it in your Laravel front end? Laravel doesn't affect your JS-code. Just change the url for the request to match the route you set up in Laravel.

Comment: And how to store the session

Comment: If you need help with your PHP-code, then show it to us so we know what you've tried. Start by [checking out the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation) and make some attempts.

Comment: in your controller where you recive id, you can put that id in the session.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  so far i didn't try to store session in laravel ,in normal php and ajax i follow the above method so here to clarify its the right way or any other good practices in laravel to store and retrieve session

Comment: Before posting, you _need_ to have tried something yourself. SO should be the _last resort_ if you really can't get your code working. Laravel have an extensive documentation, covering most aspects of the framework. There are also thousands of guides out there. There's no reason for anyone to reinvent the docs or existing guides yet again here. SO isn't a substitute for researching or studying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use same js code for Laravel. But you need to change "test_session.php" with your route url and "newredirect.php" with redirect route url.

Example Code:

```
$('.action').click(function(){
    var editaction=($(this).attr("id"));
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ROUTE URL",
        data:"test_id="+editaction,
        success:function(results){
            window.location.href="REDIRECTED ROUTE URL"
        }
    }); 
});
```

Here is example how to save session in Laravel Controller:

```
public function ExampleRoute(Request $request){
    $username = Input::get('username');
    if($username){
        $request->session()->put('username', $username);
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

If you want to get your session, you can use that controller example:

```
public function ExampleRouteOfGetSession(Request $request){
    $username = $request->session()->get('username');
    return $username;
}
```

You can see Laravel Documentation for more information - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#using-the-session

Comment: I don't think the OP's question deserves an answer, since the OP, in his own words, haven't even tried anything yet. Any answer will just legitimize the question, resulting in the OP and future visitors to keep asking the same low quality questions in the future.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  instead of  Wrongly trying and stuck up with a problem .i am just clarifying is that i am on right way ,and also  i am new to the laravel.so only iam make this question before that i searched and i didn't get exact  ans so only i post

Comment: @HarishKarthick As I pointed out, SO isn't a substitute for doing proper research and trying. Before posting, you _need_ to try something. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Tq I'll take your point next time, ill follow that

Comment: @MagnusEriksson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929807/laravel-to-get-db-values-from-session-id 

Could you please help this question